# Azure AD Connect - Change sourceanchor

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have a single forest and single domain AD scenario and I configured AD Connect with sAMAccountName as sourceanchor.
As far as I understood you cannot change sourceanchor attribute without destroying all the objects.
Did I miss anything here? I really wants to be able to change usernames and email addresses in the future, any suggestion?
Destroy and recreate all objects could be an option is there any tool/script to automate things in these cases?

Thanks,
Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

The **[sourceAnchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-connect-design-concepts#sourceanchor)** attribute is defined as an attribute immutable during the lifetime of an object.  You could use **[objectGUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ad/naming-properties#objectguid)** as the **SourceAnchor**. The objectGUID attribute is the unique identifier of a user. You also can read [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-connect-design-concepts#selecting-a-good-sourceanchor-attribute) to select a good sourceAnchor attribute.

> If you have a single forest on-premises, then the attribute you should
>   use is **objectGUID**. This is also the attribute used when you use
>   express settings in Azure AD Connect and also the attribute used by
>   DirSync.

For more details for syncing attribute process, you can read [this](https://blogs.perficient.com/2015/04/01/office-365-why-you-need-to-understand-immutableid/).

Comment: Hi Nancy, I've already read the docs (they are worth to be left as reference though) but I cannot find any path to migrate from bad to good

Comment: As the doc [linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-connect-design-concepts#changing-the-sourceanchor-attribute), `The sourceanchor attribute can only be set during initial installation. If you rerun the installation wizard, this option is read-only. If you need to change this setting, then you must uninstall and reinstall.` It seems that you have to uninstall and reinstall the Azure AD connect to change the  sourceAnchor attribute.

Comment: No, you cannot because the same doc says: "If the value for sourceAnchor is changed after the object has been exported to Azure AD, then Azure AD Connect sync throws an error and does not allow any more changes on that object before the issue has been fixed and the sourceAnchor is changed back in the source directory"

Comment: Not sure, I'm afraid that I have no enough experiences with Azure AD connect sync. You could expect someone who familiar with this or [request a ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-troubleshooting-support-howto) in MS expert for a good solution here. Good luck.